# how to select many data with array in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, model, frameworks

my controller

```
public function lemari_surat_alpha(){
    $show_dinas = dinas::all();
    $show_surat = surats::all();
    return view('frontend.daftar_surat_perdinas', compact('show_dinas','show_surat'));       
}
```

[image: this is daftar_surat_perdinas.blade.php]

I don't know to show many data with array for selecting in Model

Comment: It's look's good. just in your foreach loop you are wrote $show_surat as $show_surat...try to change to $show_surats as $show_surat

Comment: still not work.. i dunno why model cant read array

Comment: did u change variable from your controller, because you have show_surat name of var there...that not logic if is array don't name it in singular. If not that, than use dd() to chack array results :)

Comment: @Lugas Anegah Write your business logic in controller and get the final array. Loop with foreach and print the results in view file. Its bad practice to write logic in view file.

Comment: Collection {#255 ▼
  #items: array:6 [▶]
}

Comment: @Deathmras i check and i found this Collection {#255 ▼ #items: array:6 [▶] }

Comment: @laktherock oke, ill try, thanks mate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're basically trying to group the results in alphabetical order within view. Why not arrange your results first and then display it.

Try this.

```
public function lemari_surat_alpha(){
    $show_dinas = dinas::all();

    // Uppercase alphabet keys collection
    $alphabets = collect(range('A', 'Z'))->flip();

    // Grouped results
    $results = surats::all()->groupBy(function($item) {
        return strtoupper($item->nama_surat[0]);
    });

    // Merge results with alphabets
    $show_surat = $alphabets->map(function($item, $key) use ($results) {
        return $results->has($key) ? $results->get($key) : null;
    });

    return view('frontend.daftar_surat_perdinas', compact('show_dinas','show_surat'));       
}
```

This will return grouped results. Like this

[image: collection]

then you can iterate over the collection in your blade file like this

```
@foreach ($show_surat as $alphabet => $surats)

    <div class="entry-image">
        <a href="#" class="entry-link" target="_blank">
            &nbsp;
            {{ $alphabet }}
            &nbsp;
        </a>
    </div>

    @if (is_null($surats))
        No Results
    @else
        <ul style="margin-left: 20px;">
            @foreach($surats as $surat)
                <li style="font-size: 18px;">{{ $surat->nama_surat }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    @endif

@endforeach
```

Comment: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() (View: E:\Xampp\htdocs\info_surat_malang\resources\views\Frontend\daftar_surat_dinas.blade.php)

Comment: im sorry, i dont know what this code mean "@foreach($show_surat as $alphabet => $surats)"

Comment: @LugasAnegah can you show me what is the output of `$show_surat` after updating your code?

Comment: Collection {#249 ▼
  #items: array:26 [▼
    "A" => null
    "B" => null
    "C" => null
    "D" => null
    "E" => null
    "F" => null
    "G" => null
    "H" => null
    "I" => Collection {#236 ▶}
    "J" => null
    "K" => null
    "L" => null
    "M" => null
    "N" => null
    "O" => null
    "P" => null
    "Q" => null
    "R" => null
    "S" => Collection {#242 ▶}
    "T" => null
    "U" => null
    "V" => null
    "W" => null
    "X" => null
    "Y" => null
    "Z" => null
  ]
}

Comment: @LugasAnegah the output is fine. Can you show me the view file?

Comment: foreach($show_surat as $alphabet => $surats)
        <div class="entry-image">
         <a href="#" class="entry-link" target="_blank">
          &nbsp;
          {{ $alphabet }}
          &nbsp;
         </a>
        </div>  
      <ul style="margin-left: 20px;">
       @foreach($surats as $surat)      
       <li style="font-size: 18px;">
       if(is_null($surat))
                    No Results
                else
                    {{ $surat->nama_surat }}
                @endif
       </li>
       endforeach       
      </ul>
     endforeach

Comment: @LugasAnegah your view is also fine. Verify the value of `$show_surat` variable by putting this code `{{ dd($show_surat) }}` before the `foreach`. Let me know the value

Comment: sure .. i think data output is fine, dd($show_surat) work fine

Comment: @LugasAnegah ok then which error you're facing right now?

Comment: 'Invalid argument supplied for foreach() (View: E:\Xampp\htdocs\info_surat_malang\resources\views\Frontend\daftar_surat_dinas.blade.php)'

Comment: whoaaa .. work fine !! thanks you much .. i learn very much in this section
thanks @Zayn Ali >.<

Comment: @LugasAnegah Happy to help :-)

Answer (score 0):

VIEW:

```
 @foreach( $show_dinas as $show_dina){
     //do something
 @endforeach
```